# What kind of a particle has this mass?

Tags: particle-physics

I have a particle that has a mass around $(760\pm10)~MeV/c^2$ but I do not know what kind of particle it is.  [This links me to](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2013/tables/contents_tables.html) some tables that have data on all sorts of subatomic particles but it is a bit daunting to go through and figure out what kind of a particle it could be.  Does anyone know off the top of their head what kind of a particle this could be or what class of particle (baryon, meson, specific family of meson, etc.) it could be, or if there is a more effective way than sorting through LBL tables to figure out what kind of particle it is?

Comment: While the PDB is a bit of a tome, the particle listings are pretty simple. They are divided into four groups and each group is *ordered by mass*. You will quickly be able to discard the leptons and bosons leaving you to leaf through the first through few pages of mesons and baryons.

Comment: the decay modes an the experiment where it was determined  would help to remind us. The mass  is the mass of the rho meson but there are other close by resonances with different decay modes.

Comment: here is the list in wiki. omega is quite close but different decays http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mesons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this sort of task, it's easier to check through Wikipedia's [list of baryons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_baryons) and [list of mesons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mesons). Each article has a table listing the properties, including mass, of the known particles of the appropriate type, so you can just scan down the table and find the particle that matches your mass.

In addition to mesons and baryons, in general, you would need to check the three charged leptons (electron, muon, tau), the six quarks, the W and Z bosons, and the Higgs boson. Plus neutrinos, although we don't really know their masses. Those are all the massive particles that are not QCD bound states.